# Make an event when WebBrowser complete downloading the file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with WebBrowser on an ASP.NET project from the c# side.
I loaded all the libraries that needed for this (the windows.form)
but still when I'm trying to initialize it like: `WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();` it's crashing.

So in some web I found this solution:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    var webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = false;

    while (documentText == null)
    {
       documentText = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    }
 });
 thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 thread.Start();
```

but because it's not the usual way when I'm trying to use the DocumentCompleted method it's not working for me.

I also tried do it like:
`if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete){}`
and it still not worked for me.

I would like for some idea for how to make the DocumentCompleted method or some optional way.
and maybe to tell me why the usual way of: `WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();` not working.

EDIT:
The big idea is that i want an server that updating some img url spot accuring to the Html he downloaded

Comment: Where is that code? I hope it is not on the ASP.NET server side.

Comment: i writed it's on the c# side

Comment: What is your final goal? The WebBrowser control is not designed to be used this way (in a multithreaded server/service environment like IIS)

Comment: You can write applications in C# that run on the server too, so please make clear what you mean.

Comment: So you are trying to open a browser window on the server?

Comment: yes i want to make the webBrowser work on the asp.net if its possible

Comment: And who is going to administer that browser window?

Comment: @PatrickHofman how can i make an c# aplliction to run on server?

Comment: @Mayli why are you using a *web browser* control on the server in the first place? If you want to perform screen scraping, you can use `HttpClient` to retrieve web pages and an HTML parser like Anglesharp or HTML Agility Pack to parse the output. Quite often though a simple regex may be enough to retrieve a specific tag like a button or hidden field and read its value

Comment: I agree,if this code is within an asp.net application running on the server, your approach makes no sense. A web application runs without any human user (the only human is at the other end of the HTTP request, using their own browser on another device)...so it makes no sense to use a graphical object like WebBrowser - it will try to open a window, but there's no-one to show it to, and no GUI context for the execution of the code.

Comment: You mentioned a crash, but not the error message that resulted...I wouldn't be surprised if the error is related to this nonsensical usage. If you want to download data from another website, use a non-graphical HTTP client...like `HttpClient`, in fact, or `WebClient`